# Python + Tweepy (STREAM API) - Parsing JSON output for certain values/objects

Tags: python, json, parsing, twitter, tweepy

**Found answer**: I found the solution with the help of a friend. I forgot to try the `json.loads()` function - it worked with `print json.loads(data)['text']`.

**Question:**

I am attempting to experiment with Twitter's streaming API through Tweepy. I have gotten the example code to run, which filters the stream based on certain keywords and dumps the entire block of JSON information to stdout for each of these tweets.

Being new to JSON and the twitter API, I do not know how to extract a certain attribute - say, the name of the poster or the actual text of the tweet - into a string.

I have determined that the JSON output that goes to the stdout is a Unicode object, and I have no idea how to access the various elements within the JSON.

I am using Python 2.7.9 (should I upgrade to 3.x?) and Tweepy 3.3.0. The code below is a mostly-unmodified version of a random streaming API tutorial I found by Googling.

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
import json

consumer_key = "IS A SECWET"
consumer_secret = "IS A SECWET"
access_token = "IS A SECWET"
access_token_secret = "IS A SECWET"


class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print data # here I would like to print ONLY the tweet's text, not the entire JSON dump.
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status


if __name__ == '__main__':

    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, l)

    stream.filter(track=['#testing'])
```

Here is the output in the terminal from one tweet:

```
{"created_at":"Thu Jul 02 18:59:13 +0000 2015","id":616682557896290306,"id_str":"616682557896290306","text":"I am #testing again","source":"\u003ca href=\"https:\/\/about.twitter.com\/products\/tweetdeck\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTweetDeck\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":247344597,"id_str":"247344597","name":"Techniponi","screen_name":"techniponi","location":"Sugar Land, TX","url":"http:\/\/comeonandsl.am","description":"Internet Marketing Specialist for Wolf Beats, weekly DJ on PonyvilleFM (Sundays 4-5pm Central). I made music like a year ago. Skype wincam98","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":110,"friends_count":187,"listed_count":3,"favourites_count":353,"statuses_count":806,"created_at":"Fri Feb 04 16:14:13 +0000 2011","utc_offset":-18000,"time_zone":"Central Time (US & Canada)","geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"000000","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/612795294728597504\/XISJ1ccp.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/612795294728597504\/XISJ1ccp.png","profile_background_tile":true,"profile_link_color":"3B94D9","profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"000000","profile_text_color":"000000","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/612347971368148992\/Qeoo3RvD_normal.png","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/612347971368148992\/Qeoo3RvD_normal.png","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/247344597\/1431372460","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"testing","indices":[5,13]}],"trends":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1435863553867"}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution with the help of a friend. I forgot to try the `json.loads()` function - it worked with `print json.loads(data)['text']`.